# Performing Convolution (NOT cross-correlation) in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch, convolution, torch

I have [a network](https://github.com/TheAbhiKumar/tensorflow-value-iteration-networks) that I am trying to implement in pytorch, and I cannot seem to figure out how to implement "pure" convolution. In tensorflow it could be accomplished like this:

```
def conv2d_flipkernel(x, k, name=None):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, flipkernel(k), name=name,
                        strides=(1, 1, 1, 1), padding='SAME')
```

With the `flipkernel` function being:

```
def flipkernel(kern):
      return kern[(slice(None, None, -1),) * 2 + (slice(None), slice(None))]
```

How can something similar be done in pytorch?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TLDR** Use the convolution from the functional toolbox, [`torch.nn.fuctional.conv2d`](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#convolution-functions), not [`torch.nn.Conv2d`](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#convolution-layers), and flip your filter around the vertical and horizontal axis.

---

`torch.nn.Conv2d` is a convolutional layer for a network. Because weights are learned, it does not matter if it is implemented using cross-correlation, because the network will simply learn a mirrored version of the kernel (Thanks @etarion for this clarification).

`torch.nn.fuctional.conv2d` performs convolution with the inputs and weights provided as arguments, similar to the tensorflow function in your example. I wrote a simple test to determine whether, like the tensorflow function, it is actually performing cross-correlation and it is necessary to flip the filter for correct convolutional results.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.autograd as autograd
import numpy as np

#A vertical edge detection filter. 
#Because this filter is not symmetric, for correct convolution the filter must be flipped before element-wise multiplication
filters = autograd.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[[[-1, 1]]]]))

#A test image of a square
inputs = autograd.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                                             [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                                            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]]]))
print(F.conv2d(inputs, filters))
```

This outputs

```
Variable containing:
(0 ,0 ,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0 -1  0
  0  1  0  0 -1  0
  0  1  0  0 -1  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x1x5x6]
```

This output is the result for cross-correlation. Therefore, we need to flip the filter

```py
def flip_tensor(t):
    flipped = t.numpy().copy()

    for i in range(len(filters.size())):
        flipped = np.flip(flipped,i) #Reverse given tensor on dimention i
    return torch.from_numpy(flipped.copy())

print(F.conv2d(inputs, autograd.Variable(flip_tensor(filters.data))))
```

The new output is the correct result for convolution.

```
Variable containing:
(0 ,0 ,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0 -1  0  0  1  0
  0 -1  0  0  1  0
  0 -1  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x1x5x6]
```

Comment: OP asked for convolution instead of cross-correlation. I am convinced that they are aware of the fact that *learning* the weights will lead to the same result. However, if one wants to e.g. replicate a network by porting from another language and check equivalence using fixed weights, then one might find oneself in OPs situation, with this exact question - especially given the fact that pytorch has not implemented `[::-1]` yet.

Comment: `torch.nn.conv2d` now is `torch.nn.Conv2d` in CamelCase, denoting a class.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing too different from the answer above, but `torch` can do `flip(i)` natively (and I guess you only wanted to `flip(2)` and `flip(3)`):

```
def convolution(A, B):
  return F.conv2d(A, B.flip(2).flip(3), padding=padding)
```