# Different results from PyTorch's conv1d and SciPy's convolve

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch, signal-processing, convolution

I'm building a PyTorch model to estimate [Impuse Responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response).
Currently I am calculating the loss from the real and estimated impulse response.
I would like to convolve both the estimated and real impulse response with a signal and then calculate the loss from those.

The [pyroomaccoustics](https://github.com/LCAV/pyroomacoustics) package uses SciPy's `fftconvolve` to convolve the impulse response with a given signal. I cannot use this since it would break PyTorch's computation graph. PyTorch's `conv1d` uses cross-correlation. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970009/performing-convolution-not-cross-correlation-in-pytorch) it seems that by flipping the filter `conv1d` can be used for convolution.

I am confused as to why the following code gives a different result for `conv1d` and `convolve` and what must be changed to get the outputs to be equal.

```
import torch
from scipy.signal import convolve

a = torch.tensor([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])
b = torch.tensor([.0, .1, .0])

a1 = a.view(1, 1, -1)
b1 = torch.flip(b, (0,)).view(1, 1, -1)


print(torch.nn.functional.conv1d(a1, b1).view(-1))
# >>> tensor([0.0200, 0.0300, 0.0400])

print(convolve(a, b))
# >>> [0.   0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `mode` parameter of [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).  Use `mode='valid'` to match PyTorch's `conv1d`:

```
In [20]: from scipy.signal import convolve                                      

In [21]: a = np.array([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])                                     

In [22]: b = np.array([.0, .1, .0])                                             

In [23]: convolve(a, b, mode='valid')                                           
Out[23]: array([0.02, 0.03, 0.04])
```

To modify the call of PyTorch's `conv1d` to give the same output as the default behavior of `scipy.signal.convolve` (i.e. to match `mode='full'`) for this example, set `padding=2` in the call to `conv1d`.  More generally, for a given convolution kernel `b`, set the padding to `len(b) - 1`.

Comment: Setting the `conv1d` padding to `len(b) // 2 + len(b) % 2` (since b may not be odd) does not seem to give the same results as `scipy.signal.convolve` for larger convolution kernels. For example `a = torch.rand((35000,))` and `b = torch.rand((400,))`

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Try `padding=len(b) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional example pictures for full,same,valid in convolve
https://www.twblogs.net/a/5c8373f9bd9eee35fc13cb76

select [valid] will match with torch.conv1d