# Why are PyTorch "convolutions" implemented as cross-correlations?

Tags: python, pytorch, naming-conventions, convolution, cross-correlation

PyTorch convolutions are actually implemented as [cross-correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). This shouldn't produce issues in *training* a convolution layer, since one is just a flipped version of the other (and hence the learned function will be equally powerful), but it **does** [prove an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970009/performing-convolution-not-cross-correlation-in-pytorch) when:

1. trying to implement an actual convolution with the `functional` library
2. trying to copy the weights of an actual convolution from another deep learning library

The authors say the following in [Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf):

> Convolution, or more precisely, *discrete convolution*<sup>1</sup>...
>
> <sup><sup>1.</sup> There is a subtle difference between PyTorch's convolution and mathematics' convolution: one argument's sign is flipped. If we were in a pedantic mood, we could call PyTorch's convolutions *discrete cross-correlations.*</sup>

**But they don't explain *why* it was implemented like this. Is there a reason?**

Maybe something similar to how the PyTorch implementation of `CrossEntropyLoss` [isn't actually cross entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390842/cross-entropy-in-pytorch) but an analogous function taking "logits" as inputs instead of raw probabilities (to avoid [numerical instability](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#softmax))?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-are-pytorch-convolutions-implemented-as-cross-correlations/115010?u=iacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is simpler. As you said, convolution is the flipped version of cross-correlation, but that's not a problem in the context of training a CNN. So we can just avoid doing the flipping, which simplifies the code and reduces the computation time:

> The advantage of cross-correlation is that it avoids the additional step of flipping the filters to perform the convolutions.
>
> - [Performance Evaluation of cuDNN Convolution Algorithms on NVIDIA Volta GPUs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8721631)

Flipping the kernel won't have any effect on the mathematical stability. The operations remain the same.